# ¿Cómo puedo borrar entre dos carácteres con sed?

Tags: bash, sed

Tengo un fasta enorme:

```
>M03351_17_000000000-APPCH_1_1108_19837_8773    Otu0001|11237|16S1_10-16S1_11-16S1_12  
ATG-A-A-C-G-C-T-G-G-C-G-G-C-G-T-G-C
```

Así, pero repetidas  veces, y quiero borrar lo que hay entre el `>` y el `\t` pero no hay manera.

También quiero quitar lo que hay después de "Otuxxxx" hasta el final de linea. Esto sí sé, pero si tenéis alguna sugerencia mejor que la mía.

Comment: Hola Juan Alvarez, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Lo más importante es haberlo intentado. Sobre tu intento nos contextualizas en los problemas concretos que tienes y sobre ello podemos ayudarte. Si no lo has intentado, investiga y prueba. Después has de [edit] la pregunta para añadir la información que falta según [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: por favor, escribe como lo arias para lo de Otuxxxx que comentas. Si lo estas haciendo con sed y parametros, lo mas facil sera utilizar un patron que tome los simbolos > y \t como literales, y eliminar el contenido entre esos dos.

Comment: Como te comenta @Jakala, sería bueno que indicaras cómo estás haciendo lo de quitar después de "Otuxxx". Además, ¿puede haber más de un tabulador? Ayudaría tener más líneas de ejemplo, con la muerte de qué buscar tener finalmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para borrar todo lo contenido entre dos carácteres concretos, simplemente haz:

```
sed 's/X.*Y//' fichero
```

Donde `X` es el primer carácter e `Y` el segundo. Lo que hace es buscar el patrón y sustituirlo por nada, es decir, borrarlo. Este patrón irá desde la primera ocurrencia de `X` y hasta la última de `Y` en la línea dada.

En tu caso:

```
$ sed 's/^>.*\t//' fichero
Otu0001|11237|16S1_10-16S1_11-16S1_12
```

Nótese que uso `^` para designar el principio de la línea.

Answer (score 1):

Lo he solucionado así:

```
sed -r 's/(.*)(\t)/>/g' b.txt > d.txt
```

El sed coge todo hasta el tabulador y lo sustituye por un >, ya que intentar excluir el `>` del argumento con `(?<=)` me daba error.

Comment: No hace falta el `/g` pues lo haces una única vez. De hecho, con `sed 's/^>.*\t//' fichero` habría suficiente, si lo que quieres es guardar a partir de lo que hay después del último tab.

Comment: No me queda claro qué pretendías con `(_<=)`. ¿Podrías mostrarlo? Nótese que Sed no dispone de look-behind.

Comment: (?<=>)(.*)(\t) con este regex queria borrar todo lo que hay entre > y \t sin incluir el >, pero daba error asique lo cojo todo y los sustituyo por > y arrelgao. @fedorqui

Comment: Claro, es que no es una sintaxis que Sed soporte, como comenté antes. Mira mi respuesta para una versión más limpia.